# Serialization Issues in XStream

Tags: java, xml, parsing, web, xstream

So I am having a problem serializing my Java code. This is a web scraper, scraping pages from our school's course selection website for a project I'm working on and I'm trying to output all the Class information for the designated Subject in an XML file. The problem is, some classes have more than one section, and rather than just re-writing these file names and wasting space, I wanted them all to stay under a section called "Sections" in my XML. Any idea what is wrong with my code? Here's a link to the gist, I don't want to stretch the page with my code: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/3955843)

Comment: Still haven't figured out a way to get it to work . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling `List` through `xstream` is bit tricky. You need to add an `implicitCoolection` for `sections`

```
    //xstream.alias("list", Class.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(Class.class, "sections");
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @Yxes: Try enabling the first line i.e. add the alias as well: `xstream.alias("list", Class.class);`. This worked for me.

Comment: @Yxes: Good. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking arrow sign down the vote counts in front of the answer.