# Array Conversion in Xstream Parser

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Hi am trying to convert the following xml into object using Xstream parser.
I tried using the below code to convert the xml but am getting

```
Duplicate field ERRORS
---- Debugging information ----
field               : ERRORS
class               : com.avidev9.Fees.GCSFeesResponse$DebitsWSDS
required-type       : com.avidev9.Fees.GCSFeesResponse$DebitsWSDS
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /DebitsWSDS/ERRORS[2]
line number         : 1
version             : null
```

The Code I used

```
   xstream.alias("DebitsWSDS", DebitsWSDS.class);
            xstream.alias("DEBITS", DebitsWSDS.DEBITS.class);
            xstream.alias("list", DebitsWSDS.class);
            xstream.addImplicitCollection(DebitsWSDS.class, "ERRORS");


            xstream.alias("ERROR_ID", String.class);
            xstream.alias("TABLE_NAME", String.class);
            xstream.alias("TABLE_ID", String.class);
            xstream.alias("ROW_ID", String.class);
            xstream.alias("ERROR_TEXT", String.class);
            xstream.alias("ERROR_CODE", String.class);
            xstream.alias("COLUMN_ID", String.class);
            xstream.alias("ERROR_TYPE", String.class);
```

XML

```
  <DebitsWSDS xmlns="">
        <DEBITS>
            <DEBIT_ID>-1</DEBIT_ID>
            <ACCOUNT_ID>12321312313</ACCOUNT_ID>
            <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2012-12-12T00:00:00-06:00</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <DAY_OF_MONTH>12</DAY_OF_MONTH>
            <DEBIT_TYPE>S</DEBIT_TYPE>
            <OCCURS_NUM>1</OCCURS_NUM>
            <DEBIT_AMOUNT>750</DEBIT_AMOUNT>
            <MEMO>S</MEMO>
            <ACTIVE_FLAG>Y</ACTIVE_FLAG>
            <MODIFIED_BY/>
            <DEBIT_AUTHORIZED/>
            <DEBIT_AUTHORIZED_BY/>
            <REMAINING_OCCURRENCES>0</REMAINING_OCCURRENCES>
        </DEBITS>

        <ERRORS>
            <ERROR_ID>1</ERROR_ID>
            <TABLE_NAME>Debits</TABLE_NAME>
            <TABLE_ID>-1</TABLE_ID>
            <ROW_ID>0</ROW_ID>
            <COLUMN_ID>EXCEPTION</COLUMN_ID>
            <ERROR_TYPE>E</ERROR_TYPE>
            <ERROR_CODE>4</ERROR_CODE>
            <ERROR_TEXT>This debit type is not allowed for this company and policy group</ERROR_TEXT>
        </ERRORS>

        <ERRORS>
            <ERROR_ID>2</ERROR_ID>
            <TABLE_NAME>Clients</TABLE_NAME>
            <TABLE_ID/>
            <ROW_ID>0</ROW_ID>
            <COLUMN_ID>CLOSE_SCHED_DATE</COLUMN_ID>
            <ERROR_TYPE>E</ERROR_TYPE>
            <ERROR_CODE>4</ERROR_CODE>
            <ERROR_TEXT>Client has been closed.  Cannot Authorize Draft.</ERROR_TEXT>
        </ERRORS>

        <ERRORS>
            <ERROR_ID>3</ERROR_ID>
            <TABLE_NAME>Debits</TABLE_NAME>
            <TABLE_ID>-1</TABLE_ID>
            <ROW_ID>0</ROW_ID>
            <COLUMN_ID>EXCEPTION</COLUMN_ID>
            <ERROR_TYPE>E</ERROR_TYPE>
            <ERROR_CODE>4</ERROR_CODE>
            <ERROR_TEXT>Cannot Schedule a Debit or Draft.  Client has been closed.</ERROR_TEXT>
        </ERRORS>

            <ERRORS>
                <ERROR_ID>1</ERROR_ID>
                <TABLE_NAME>Debits</TABLE_NAME>
                <TABLE_ID>-1</TABLE_ID>
                <ROW_ID>0</ROW_ID>
                <COLUMN_ID>ACTIVE_FLAG</COLUMN_ID>
                <ERROR_TYPE>W</ERROR_TYPE>
                <ERROR_CODE>4</ERROR_CODE>
                <ERROR_TEXT>Creating debit on inactive Client account.</ERROR_TEXT>
            </ERRORS>
    </DebitsWSDS>
```

My class structure.

```
   package com.avidev9.Fees;

import java.util.List;

public class DebitsWSDS {
        public List<ERROR> ERRORS;
        public DEBITS DEBITS;

    public class ERROR {
        public String TABLE_NAME;
        public String TABLE_ID;
        public String ERROR_ID;
        public String ROW_ID;
        public String ERROR_TEXT;
        public String ERROR_CODE;
        public String COLUMN_ID;
        public String ERROR_TYPE;
    }

    public class DEBITS {
        public String EFFECTIVE_DATE;
        public String ACTIVE_FLAG;
        public String ACCOUNT_ID;
        public String DEBIT_AUTHORIZED_BY;
        public String DAY_OF_MONTH;
        public String DEBIT_ID;
        public String MEMO;
        public String REMAINING_OCCURRENCES;
        public String DEBIT_TYPE;
        public String OCCURS_NUM;
        public String DEBIT_AMOUNT;
        public String DEBIT_AUTHORIZED;
        public String MODIFIED_BY;
    }

}
```

Comment: Some how was able to parse it without errors. But I cannot access the List<Errors>. Whenever am trying to access the List is giving com.avidev9.Fees.DebitsWSDS cannot be cast to com.avidev9.Fees.DebitsWSDS$ERROR
 at com.avidev9.XmlTest

Answer (score 0):

Handling List through xstream is bit tricky. You need to add an implicitCoolection for sections

```
xstream.alias("list", ERRORS.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(ERRORS.class, "ERRORS");
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: :( Well didnt worked. Am getting No field "ERRORS" for implicit collection

Comment: @Avidev9: I forgot to mention. Use the list field name in `GCSFeesResponse` class. This worked for me and for the other OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078289/serialization-issues-in-xstream

Comment: ur solution seems promising. But am getting error  No such field com.avidev9.Fees.DebitsWSDS.ERRORS
---- Debugging information ----
field               : ERRORS
class               : com.avidev9.Fees.DebitsWSDS
required-type       : com.avidev9.Fees.DebitsWSDS
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /DebitsWSDS/ERRORS
line number         : 1
version             : null

Updated the question body as well

Answer (score 0):

In your Class, you have a combination of String and Integer Variable. But While using alias(), you were mentioning only `String.class`.

You should declare all the variable as String and try running you code.

Comment: Well, Can you remove <MODIFIED_BY/>, <DEBIT_AUTHORIZED/> and <DEBIT_AUTHORIZED_BY/> in your XML and run, as you dont have any values for them?

Comment: Well cannot remove them as they are returned from a webservice

Comment: I suspect only that causes the issue. Try to remove them and run it seperately and tell me if it works.

Comment: Well tried but didnt worked. Still getting error " No such field com.avidev9.Fees.DebitsWSDS.ERRORS"